# Is portforwarding necessary for website without a domain

Tags: raspberry-pi, port, portforwarding, vs-web-site-project

I am quite ignorant to the nitty gritty of networking. I am about to create a program for the raspberry pi that tells me the humidity of the room, then proceeds to put it on a web page.

I know how to set this up for **my network**, but if i wanted to give it to some random person then a problem presents itself.

My question is, it it possible to host a website without a domain, and without port forwarding. And connect to it by http://publiciphere:porthere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your raspberry pi is hosted on a private network you would need to configure your router to forward requests on a given port (e.g. 80) to your internal ip for the pi.